# CQLSH cannot connect - TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments'

Tags: python, macos, cassandra, cqlsh

I am trying to get CQLSH to connect to my local Cassandra on my Mac, but am getting the following error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})
```

I have tried all of the suggestions on the other questions relating to this problem, I have set `CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=TRUE`, and the location of my cassandra binaries is added to `PATH`.  Cassandra is definitely running and doesn't report any errors on startup with `cassandra`

```
$ cassandra -v
2.2.3

$ cqlsh --version
cqlsh 5.0.1

$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

I was having the following error when trying to use the latest version (3.8.1) of the cassandra-driver:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/meanwhileinhell/opt/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py", line 111, in <module>
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster, PagedResult
ImportError: cannot import name PagedResult
```

After reading, I found that the API had changed in version 3.0 so reverted to version 2.7.2 of the cassandra-driver.  Now I get the `Unable to connect...` error.

Anymore information of my environment I can provide, please ask.

===EDIT===

Running CQLSH with debug gives two additional lines, but provides no other useful information:

```
$ cqlsh localhost 9042 --debug
Using CQL driver: <module 'cassandra' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/__init__.pyc'>
Using connect timeout: 5 seconds
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'localhost': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})
```

Comment: try cqlsh <rpc_address configured in yaml file> <cql_port configured in yaml file> E.g. "cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042". and provide the complete error you get in the cmd prompt/terminal

Comment: So ran `cqlsh localhost 9042` (as `localhost` is the value of `rpc_address`) and got the exact same error as above, only the one line.  I noticed in my `cassandra.yml` that there is no property named `cql_port`, 9042 is only defined with the property `native_transport_port`.  I have made no changes to this YAML file at all, its straight out-of-the-box.  I've updated my question with the debug output.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam, that must have been it.  I installed pyenv and then Python version 2.7.10, then after re-installing v2.7.2 of the cassandra-driver it now connects.